# How did a DApp get events when it has subscribed them?

Tags: events, frontend, client, blockchain, smartcontracts

I'm new to smart contract. Recently I learned that smart contracts can emit events when it is being executed, and front end of a DApp can subscribe specific events, make responses when events are emitted.

My question is: when did the DApp receive the events, is it true that the contract will send a message to the node which runs the DApp ? Or the node just passively wait until a block containing the specific transactions arrive, and scan through the logs to get events?

Just to mention, I'm not interested in how to use apis like web3.js, but curious about the mechanism behind them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When a block producer (validator on PoS, miner on PoW) publishes a block, the block contains state changes including event logs.

Each node learns about this new block from its neighbors (i.e. other nodes that it knows of).

Then it depends on the way how your DApp communicates with the specific node. Usually it keeps a websocket channel where the node proactively informs the DApp about new event logs. Or the DApp polls the node over an HTTP connection (e.g. every 10 seconds or so), keeps asking the node about new event logs, and the node replies with the list of new event logs.

`web3js` and similar libraries are "just" wrappers to these forms of communication - usually it's either [websockets](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/using-websockets/) or HTTP-based [RPC API](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getfilterchanges).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I see that when a smart contract "emit" some events, it does not directly broadcast them, but write them to logs. Other nodes will get these events when they get the block.